# Getting an Int from a UITextField and Limiting UITextField to Ints

Tags: iphone

I'm very new to iPhone programming, but am trying to delve into it.

I have an interface setup in interface builder. I am trying to have the user input numbers, in which I will use to calculate a value.

Thus, I have two UITextFields. What I want to do is to access these numbers (ints) that the user inputs. How do I go about doing this? is it simply blah.text (blah being my UITextField). Also, is there a way to only allow a user to input ints into the UITextField? Sorry if these questions sound so elementary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about `[blah.text intValue]` ?

which is using NSString's [`intValue`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/intValue) method.

If you want to *limit* the UITextField to numbers, set the keyboard for that text field to only work with numbers (i.e. click on the text field in the XIB and in the Attributes inspector, set the "Keyboard" to be "Number Pad").

Answer (score 3):

You can access the `int` value of a string (returned by `UITextField`'s `text` property) by using the `intValue` method.

**Pseudocode:**

```
UITextField *blah;
int number = [blah intValue];
```

As for inputting numbers, you can restrict the user to ONLY numbers by setting the `UITextField`'s `keyboardType` property to anything from [this typedef](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006896-CH3-DontLinkElementID_26).

**Pseudocode:**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    UITextField *blah;
    blah.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

there are a couple of approaches to do this.
1] You can restrict user to enter only numeric values by implementing UITextField's delegate methods

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;   // return NO to not change text
```

to check and allow if user has input only numeric values from set "0123456789".

2] Present keyboard with type Numeric so it will presnt him with options to enter only numeric values (Though it will not stop him from copy/pasting any alphanumeric value).

Finally to extract the integer value you need to access the value as

```
NSInteger requiredInt = [[YOUR_TEXTFIELD text] intValue];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: An attached physical keyboard will allow users to submit other characters so you must always use both methods.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to accept only the numbers input in TextField, you can set keyboardType property to UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad.

[blahTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];